# Need help with complex query

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

My result set seems fine except I'm getting additional duplicate results which I want to avoid, here is that case:

I'm using two tables :

order

```
id|companyname|routeid|orderdate
1 |company1   | 23dsa | 
2 |company1   | 23dsa | 2011-04-28
3 |company1   | 23dsa | 2011-04-05
4 |company2   | 24gcc | 2011-22-05
```

vehicle

```
id| vehiclename | routeid
1 | van1        | 23dsa 
2 | van2        | 24gcc
```

This is my query 1 :

```
select t1.companyname, max(t1.orderdate) as orderdate
from order t1, vehicle t2 where t1.routeid=t2.routeid
group by t1.companyname, t1.orderdate
order by t1.id
```

This is query 2 :

```
 select t1.companyname, max(t1.orderdate) as orderdate
    from order t1, vehicle t2 where t1.routeid=t2.routeid
    group by t1.companyname, t1.orderdate having count(1) = 1
    order by t1.id
```

This is my result :

```
companyname | orderdate
company1    |  
company1    | 2011-04-28
company1    | 2011-04-05
company2    | 2011-22-05
```

I'd like it to be like this :

```
companyname | orderdate
company1    | 2011-04-28
company2    | 2011-22-05
```

I was missing is not null :

```
select t1.companyname, max(t1.orderdate) as orderdate
    from order t1, vehicle t2 where t1.orderdate is not null and t1.routeid=t2.routeid
    group by t1.companyname, t1.orderdate
    order by t1.id
```

Comment: Is there any reason you are involving the second table?

Comment: @Henry yes I only those to match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
SELECT
    companyname, MAX(orderdate) AS orderdate
FROM
    `order`
GROUP BY
    companyname
ORDER BY
    id
```

And if you need that vehicle stuff in there:

```
SELECT
    companyname, MAX(orderdate) AS orderdate
FROM
    `order` o, vehicle v
WHERE
    o.routeid=v.routeid
GROUP BY
    companyname
ORDER BY
    o.id
```

Comment: thank you for your response, I think your version 2 is same as mine query version 1

Comment: @Gandalf it's not the same because you were grouping by orderdate which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.companyname, max(t1.orderdate) as orderdate
from order t1, vehicle t2 where t1.routeid=t2.routeid
group by t1.companyname
order by t1.id
```

There is no need to group by orderdate, because you only select one.